How to display tabbed codeblock in markdown (leetcode platform)?
Image for reference :
snippet from solution shared by one of the user on leetcode

I would like to create such tabbed codeblock in markdown to share my solutions on leetcode.
Is there a extension/way to do it on leetcode(markdown) ?

I tried using html+js but it is not working as expected.

After some trial and error i was able to get the expected behavior of codeblock
Answer :
you have to write codeblock one after other without any text in between. (refer image below)
markdown img on leetcode
